# How to add text to label in CSS

Tags: css

I need a smart way to add red asterisk to text placed between label tags.
Is there any way to intercept the content and add some extra text? I can add a class to this labels if necessary.
I must do it in CSS.

For ex:

```
<label> Name and surname </label>
<input type="text" required name="NameSurname">
```

shoud be:
Name and surname*****

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a pseudo-selector (`label[required]`) to choose all labels that are required, then add content (`content: "*";`) after (`::after`) the element's content.

```css
label[required]::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label required>Required</label><br>
<label>Not required</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
label::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It will cause to add to all inputs, but what if I would rather not all labels?

Comment: If you can add a class to the label then you can use `label.required-class::after { ..... } `